# PHP Docbloc: change inherited method to standard link @inheritDoc - best practice?

Tags: php, docblocks

I have a ton of lines of PHP. Many methods contain docblocks that are actually inherited from the method they override.

Example:

```
MyBaseClass {

    /**
     * @param string $first - first name
     * @param string $last  - last name
     */    
    protected function MyMethod($first, $last) 
    {

    }


    /**
     * @return bool
     */    
    public function MyMethod2($first, $last) 
    {

    }

}

MyChildClass extends MyBaseClass {

    /**
     * @param string $first - first name
     * @param string $last  - last name
     */    
    protected function MyMethod($first, $last) 
    {

    }


    /**
     * @return bool
     */    
    public function MyMethod2($first, $last) 
    {

    }

}
```

Basically, I would like the docblocks in the child class to read:

```
/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
```

Because as I understand it this is best practice.  If this is best practice, can someone recommend me what program / trick / code I can use to change all these inherited docs into the basic one above?

Answer (score 1):

PhpStorm should be able to do [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16547) -- so there should should be a checkbox to enable inserting `inheritDoc` if you extend the methods using [PhpStorm's override/extend method UI](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/_persistent/Screenshot%20from%202015-07-02%2014%3A22%3A32.png?file=74-239712&c=true&rw=473&rh=595&u=1435836276510&c=true&rw=1330&rh=1171). There are also extra plugins to tweak that behaviour, e.g. [this one](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7656-php-inheritdoc-helper).

Comment: That is a great answer.  Are there any simpler tools (I use ATOM and I am not so keen to change)? THANK YOU

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that familiar with Atom plugins.